# Is it worth just upgrading my CPU / GPU or should I just create an entirely new machine?

Tags: computer-building

I recently noticed that I'm not having a smooth gaming experience on my machine anymore. Last time I upgraded some pieces was atleast 3 years ago I think and if I recall correctly I think my CPU is my oldest part.

I don't know anything about this stuff, so I came here to ask for help.

Here are my parts:

- **Processor**: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
- **RAM**: 12 GB
- **Video Card**: AMD Radeon R9 200 Series (Dedicated Memory 3.0 GB)
- **HD**: 1 TB
- **SSD**: 120 GB

I run on 2 monitors (1920x1080 & 1600x1080). I mainly code (using programs like PHPStorm & Visual Studio Code) and game.

I'm pretty sure my CPU is the bottleneck, I'm just not sure how hard it's dragging the performance down and how far behind the rest of my hardware is compared to today's standards. 
If you guys need more info, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Best CPU you can get is 4790K which is close enough to 7700k. Also, make sure your RAM is good quality (at least 1600Mhz). Note that hardware recommendations are considered off-topic on this site.

Comment: You forgot the most important part, mentioning which motherboard you have.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare your parts with the mother board. If mother board abilities are limited to your current configuration, then there is not much you can do.
Else you can read more info about your mother board and see if the details that can be replaced worth it.

p.s. next time type in if you have desktop PC or notebook with "Motherboard" / "Notebook model name", so that other users can help you most.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your system is pretty good, so you only have to upgrade it. I would recommend you to buy an Intel core i7 2600 and buy at least 4gb more RAM (The more the better).

If you have enough money, buy at least Nvidia GeForce gtx 1060 or something better.

As I told, the cheapest way is to buy more RAM